# Chrome's fonts are too light to read

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, resolution

I have a problem with some websites. The displayed font is too light. 
My SO is W8.1 Update 1. I have a laptop with 1920x1080 screen resolution. 
It happens only with Google Chrome.
The hardware acceleration is on.

Here i post some pictures. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHHwZ.png 
 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHUH6.png

Comment: This still seems to be a problem on an external monitor connected to a laptop.

Answer (score 8):

I know it's a very old question, but in my case it turned out that I only had Roboto Thin installed on my computer. I downloaded all the other Roboto fonts from [here](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/roboto), installed them, relauched Chrome, and now it works!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same Problem and figured out, that this happend with the *Open Sans* Font. The reason was that I had *installed* this font before on my computer, but only the light-weight version.
I solved it by **uninstalling** the font from windows.

Maybe check out if this happens to you only with a specific font and try the same

Answer (score 0):

You can change your font settings by going to the Chrome menu, clicking on "settings", then "show advanced settings"
https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95416?hl=en

Have you tried zooming in and out? That can often mess up the appearance of some fonts. Try resetting your zoom to 100% (also in the Chrome menu).

Comment: The zoom page doesn't affect the font. I changed the font in the advanced settings but even this doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Ok. You can try looking at your encoding settings. Mine defaults to Unicode UTF-8. 
https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95290?hl=en

Do you have a sample link instead of just a screen capture?

Comment: Link of what? The website link of screens? btw I use utf8 too.

Answer (score -1):

I tried to zoom in and out, and change the fonts in Chrome's advanced settings. Both didn't work. I then did the same as [Mikhail Dudin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47416229) and deleted a light font that I downloaded. For him it was Roboto Thin, but for me it was Helvetica Neue Ultra Light so I think it varies per person. This fixed things for me.

Comment: Sorry, but I have to note that the fix I suggested wasn't just to delete a Roboto Thin, but to download some other (don't know which exactly) Roboto fonts that I didn't have :) I personally had problems on Google's sites, e.g. Youtube, Google.com, etc, as they are using Roboto very extensively